# Dynamically add fields to http_build_query

Tags: php, arrays, curl, dynamically-generated

I have built an API that I want to test. By that reason I'm building a simple client to try out the different features (CRUD). Below is the function for updating a producer, which works fine. However, I also want to be able to update *parts* of a producer, e.g. address (/producers/8?method=put&address=milkyway).

The array producer always contains the same elements (name, address, zipcode etc) but I only want to update the producer with the elements in the array which contains of anything. What I mean with that is that if for example the *name* element in the array is empty then name shouldn't be included in *http_build_query*. If only the *name* element contains of anything then only name should be updated.

So, let's say that the array (except for *id* that of course is mandatory) contains of address. How can I dynamically add only that to *http_build_query* ?

Thanks in advance!

```
public function UpdateProducer($producer) {

    $url = 'http://localhost/webbteknik2/Labb2/api/v1/producers/ . $producer['id'] . '?method=put';

    $data = http_build_query(array(
        'name' => $producer['name'],
        'address' => $producer['address'],
        'zipcode' => $producer['zipcode'],
        'town' => $producer['town'],
        'url' => $producer['url'],
        'imgurl' => $producer['imgurl'],
        'latitude' => $producer['latitude'],
        'longitude' => $producer['longitude'],
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ...
    the rest of the curl code
}
```

Note: I know this is bad coding in many ways, but as I said I only, asap want to be able to test the CRUD functionality through the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `array_filter` to remove the empty elements....

```
$params = array(
    'name' => $producer['name'],
    'address' => $producer['address'],
    'zipcode' => $producer['zipcode'],
    'town' => $producer['town'],
    'url' => $producer['url'],
    'imgurl' => $producer['imgurl'],
    'latitude' => $producer['latitude'],
    'longitude' => $producer['longitude'],
);

$data = http_build_query(array_filter($params, 'is_null'));
```

Comment: You should use `is_null` as the callback. Otherwise, you filter falsy values like string 0

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot for a fast and good answer!